# Laravel 5.2 add one more condition to login in standard Auth controller

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I'm trying to add one condition to laravel standard auth. I have found a lot of forums with this question. Most of them make change in vendor folder, what I don't want to do. I also found a way of adding credentials(Request $request) function in AuthController.php, but I have no luck. It looks like this:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    return array_merge($request->only($this->username(), 'password'),
        ['Type' => 1]);

}
```

Does anyone solve this issue or can advice me what to do? Thanks

Comment: You will have to override the default method from auth controller. and make new based on your requirement.

Comment: I added credentials method, it does not exist in AuthController. And what do you mean "make new based on your requirement"?

Comment: what exactly you want to do

Comment: I want to add one condition in the query for login. I need something like this:  select * from User where Username="xxxx" and Type=1.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the function your can use in AuthController to override the login function:

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            array(
                'user_name' => 'required',
                'password' => 'required',
            ),
            array(
            )
        );

        if($validator->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->errors(),'invalid_credentials');
        }

        if (!\Auth::validate(['user_name' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password])) {


            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('user_name'))->withErrors([
                'user_name' => 'Incorrect Username or Password',
            ],'invalid_credentials');
        }

        $credentials  = array('user_name' => $request->user_name, 'password' => $request->password);

        if (\Auth::attempt($credentials, true)){

            /* Check your user type condition */
            if(\Auth::User()->type == '1'){
                return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
            }
            else{
                \Auth::logout();
                return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('user_name'))->withErrors([
                    'user_name' => 'Your type validation message',
                ],'invalid_credentials');
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('user_name'))->withErrors([
            'user_name' => 'Incorrect email address or password',
        ],'invalid_credentials');
    }
```

Hope this helps you.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, first- I don't have login method, should I add it? Second - as I understand from the logic above, you check "type" after successful login, I don't need this, I need to add condition inside of the query, not check after login.

Comment: Firstly, yes.. You have to add the login method to override the default method. Secondly you can override the other functions too..

Comment: OK, I understand,thanks, let me try. So yuo say,when I add credentials methos in AuthController, it overwrite the default credentials methos right?

Comment: yes, this worked. I added getCredentials and Lodin methods to AuthController, also added needed changes in Login method. It works perfectly. Thanks for your help

Comment: can you please accept the answer so that it can be useful for others